# PHP loop with specific $_REQUEST

Tags: php

Is it possible to loop based on a specific variable name for a `$_REQUEST` for example:

```
if (!$POST)
{
do something
}

else {

if ($_REQUEST['name1'])
{
do something
}
elseif ($_REQUEST['name2'])
{
do something
}

}
```

Comment: I really have no clue what you mean

Comment: Yes you can loop and check if `$_REQUEST` contains keys matching some name pattern, but it's probably not the best way to do whatever you're trying to do. Why don't you have your form/URL send an array of names instead of `name1`, `name2`, etc?

Comment: I shall try to clarify - for the `if` and `else if` loops, is it possible to have loops which execute based on whether the URL is: `name1` or `name2`?

Comment: ...yes, where you wrote "do something" under `name1`, put the loop for `name1`. Where you wrote "do something" under `name2`, put the loop for `name2`. You haven't really clarified why there is a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really you can get as complex as you want:

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $val)
{
    switch($key)
    {
        case 'name1':
            if(is_array($val))
            {
                foreach($val as $v)
                {
                     // do something for each element in the $_REQUEST['name1'] array
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // do something for $_REQUEST['name1'] which is not an array
            }
            break;

        case 'name2':
            if(is_array($val))
            {
                foreach($val as $v)
                {
                     // do something for each element in the $_REQUEST['name2'] array
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // do something for $_REQUEST['name2'] which is not an array
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the "do something" parts in your example can be loops or whatever other code you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "do something" with the code you want for each request type.